# rfcomm service not working for Bluetooth over serial

Tags: bluetooth, serial, serial-console, services

I'm trying to connect with a terminal to my Raspberry Pi over Bluetooth, however with my current configuration (which is what I have found in numerous places online) when any device pairs and connects to the Pi, it drops out in about 3 seconds and looses the connection.

I can seem to connect if I ssh in through usb and run `sudo /usr/bin/rfcomm watch hci0 1 getty rfcomm0 115200 vt100 -a pi` manually, however I don't understand what the issues are with the current setup.

My end goal is for a paired device to be able to connect, run a terminal, and then disconnect without ever needing to interface with the board in any other way.

WiFi is not an option as we're on a public network.

I've made shell scripts to edit and setup an image, which you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/ekohilas/a73233055b8beee2490129cfaf8192ca).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is this current configuration?

Comment: @Human sorry I'm not understanding your question

Comment: @Evan Any luck? I have the same problem